# Xbee not communicating well

Tags: xbee, quartus, zigbee

I tried to establish a communicating between two Xbee's as COORDINATOR and ROUTER, this works well in XCTU as they talk well with each other but when I connect De0 nano fpga board with the one Xbee and try to send a specific letter, eg A, I am not receiving (A) on the other end (coordinator).

I am Receiving Rand characters like ?, etc.

I am providing the links of the configuration done by me in these Xbees

- https://youtu.be/1-YSk-Y52Gs
- https://youtu.be/wO3XCLA6IdM

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you verified that your serial code on the FPGA code is working correctly?  Can you test it with another TTL-level serial device (like an FTDI TTL-232R)?

Are you using the correct baud rate for the XBee configuration (based on `ATBD` setting)?

Have you connected TX, RX, CTS, RTS and ground between the FPGA and the XBee?

Comment: My code is working fine and i also checked it with the USB to UART module and receiving A perfectly, Yes i am using correct Baud rate ased on ATBD setting , I have connected ONLY RX,VCC,GND pin with the FPGA.

Comment: Can you try eliminating the XBee modules and directly connecting the FPGA's TX/RX/GND to the RX/TX/GND on the receiving end?  That would verify that you're sending data correctly.  If you put the XBee in to API mode, can the FPGA send an AT Command frame and parse the response?  That would verify communications to the local XBee are working correctly.  Also, if the coordinator sends data to the router (FPGA), can it read that data correctly?